# How do you do custom formatting with the uniq -c option?

Tags: unix, uniq

From wikipedia:

> uniq
> -c Generate an output report in default style except that each line is preceded by a count of the number of times it occurred. If this option is specified, the -u and -d options are ignored if either or both are also present.

On my machine it is taking the count number and putting it on the start of each line.  What I want is for it to be placed at the end of the line, after a comma.  How can this be done?

Example:

```
aa
aa
bb
cc
cc
dd
```

Should change to:

```
aa,2
bb,1
cc,2
dd,1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i] | "sort"}' OFS="," filename
```

**or**

```
awk -v OFS="," '{print $2,$1}' <(uniq -c file)
```

**or**

```
uniq -c file | awk '{printf("%s,%s\n",$2,$1)}'
```

**or**

```
while IFS=' +|,' read count text; do 
    echo "$text, $count"; 
done < <(uniq -c tmp)
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
aa
aa
bb
cc
cc
dd

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i] | "sort"}' OFS="," file
aa,2
bb,1
cc,2
dd,1
```

#### Test2:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v OFS="," '{print $2,$1}' <(uniq -c file)
aa,2
bb,1
cc,2
dd,1
```

#### Test3:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] while IFS=' +|,' read count text; do 
echo "$text,$count"; 
done < <(uniq -c tmp)
aa,2
bb,1
cc,2
dd,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple things like this, `sed` is easier than `awk`

`uniq -c inputfile.txt | sed -e 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\) \(.\+\)/\2,\1/'`

Comment: ...although sometimes more cryptic.

Comment: Doesnt this make a second pass however to get it done?  Is there a faster method which just does everything in one pass?  Or are the passes done at the same time anyways?

Comment: @Jonah - this and Jaypal's answer both use the Unix Way of Doing Things... constructing a pipeline of simple tools. You _are_ invoking two separate programs, but connecting the output of `uniq` to the input of `sed` they do execute concurrently - sed doesn't have to wait for uniq to finish, and on a multi-core or multi-processor machine the do actually execute in parallel. (I would have done his Test2 as `uniq -c file | awk -v blah-blah-blah` as I think it's clearer that you're doing the uniq followed by the awk (or sed))

Comment: @Jonah If you want everything to be done in one-pass then my first solution does that. It does not use `uniq`. It stores your file in an array and uses a for loop to print the values out. It does sort them as it was how you wanted your output to look like. `awk` has associative arrays which causes the output to get printed randomly.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you for correcting me. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `awk` as I find it most readable

```
% uniq -c /path/to/input_file | awk -v OFS=',' '
{
    print $2, $1
}
'
aa,2
bb,1
cc,2
dd,1
```